# CSS Data not changing according to value (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey so right now I'm learning Mainly JS but that also comes with HTML and CSS so I guess that too. I followed a great tutorial from Web Dev Simplified on how to make a snake game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTcIXok9wNY&t=1781s). so now I wanted to expand my knowledge and start adding features to the game. So I wanted to add a Score feature. The only thing is that when I change the the `text-align` or the `font-size` bigger then it already is, nothing changes, is there anything externally locking this data?

Index.html:

```
<style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: black;
    }

    #game-board {
      background-color: white;
      width: 100vmin;
      height: 100vmin;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(21, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(21, 1fr);
    }

    .snake {
      background-color: hsl(216, 100%, 50%);
      border: .25vmin solid black;
    }

    .food {
      background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
      border: .25vmin solid black;
    }

    #score {
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-size: 60;
      text-align: center;
      text-align: top;
    }
```

Main JS File:

```
import { update as updateSnake, draw as drawSnake, SNAKE_SPEED, getSnakeHead, snakeIntersection, scorefunc} from './snake.js'
import { update as updateFood, draw as drawFood } from './food.js'
import { outsideGrid } from './grid.js'

let lastRenderTime = 0
let gameOver = false
const gameBoard = document.getElementById('game-board')

function main(currentTime) {
  if (gameOver) {
    if (confirm('You lost. Press ok to restart.')) {
      window.location = '/'
    }
    return
  }


  window.requestAnimationFrame(main)
  const secondsSinceLastRender = (currentTime - lastRenderTime) / 1000
  if (secondsSinceLastRender < 1 / SNAKE_SPEED) return


  lastRenderTime = currentTime

  update()
  draw()
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(main)

function update() {
  updateSnake()
  updateFood()
  checkDeath()
  scorefunc()
}

function draw() {
  gameBoard.innerHTML = ''
  drawSnake(gameBoard)
  drawFood(gameBoard)
}

function checkDeath() {
  gameOver = outsideGrid(getSnakeHead()) || snakeIntersection()
}
```

All other files will be on my GitHub: https://github.com/CarsCanadian/snake-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add your HTML. Your javascript is unnecessary to show. Anyway, by following your link, I could locate where things went wrong. You need to add a unit to your font-size.

Your code.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#score {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="game-board"></div>
  <em id="score">123123</em>
</body>
```

Corrected code, using `font-size: 60px`.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#score {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="game-board"></div>
  <em id="score">123123</em>
</body>
```